# Could I supply linux binaries of my program with shared libraries of my system?

Tags: c++, linux, licensing, libraries

As I've haven't found a proper way to link program (writteln in c++) statically if I'm going to use plug-ins in it (linker warns that dlopen require glibc shared libraries at runtime). Also I'm not able not build dynamically-linked binaries for most of linux distibutions currently, so I could either distribute source only or try to distribute binaries along with shared libraries found in my system by `ldd`, for example:

```
libc.so.6
libdl.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
```

since I suppose that it is more easy for user to be asked to add to `.bash_profile`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path to program directory>
```

than to compile program and plugins from scratch.

So, first of all, am I right that I could re-distribute those libraries freely because they are licensed under GNU LGPL?

And does it makes any sense to do it, will the program run in most linux distributions and its versions correctly?

Comment: it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to distribute binaries is to *publish your program in source form with a free license* (like GPL); then distribution makers (and contributors) will eventually package your program for their distribution (and you don't have to bother with that).

Otherwise, you could distribute binary packages for some few major Linux distributions (eg `.deb`for Debian or Ubuntu with  `.rpm` for Redhat or Centos or Mandriva).

Some non-free software (like AMD/ATI *Catalyst fglrx* for driving ATI graphics card) are distributed in a form which generates appropriate binary packages (on the end-user machine).

All the libraries you mention are available in every standard not too old Linux distribution. You don't need to distribute them, just mention that you need them (and give a precise list of them, with their version number).

I would really **avoid  [re-] distributing the system libraries** like `libc.so.6` or `libstdc++.so.6`; the main reason to avoid distributing them is that your user (installing your copies on his system) will very probably make a big mess on his own system (and that could break other existing programs, which will make your user pissed off). Of course, if you choose (wrongly in my opinion) to distribute them, you have to comply with their license. But your users already have them, and by re-distributing them you *increase the probability of a big mess*. So just give the binary executable of your program (suitably packaged), without the system libraries that it requires.

All package managers (and package formats) deal with dependencies (on other packages), so will install e.g. `libstdc++.so.6` in the rare cases when the user's system don't have it already.

Comment: Yup, I will publish source of my program, indeed, under GPL, but I'm sure no distro will package it on many reasons (only few people will use it and, well, in fact, I'm not ready to provide something like .configure scripts and so on) OK, I could give list of library names... but couldn't different versions put into trouble? For example, couldn't a little older or a little never `glibc` provide different symbol names in its library although it would have same name `libc.so.6`?

Comment: I believe you are wrong. Eventually (within one year or two) someone will package your program. And if you publish in GPL license the source code, don't bother publishing binaries!

Comment: I need to publish Windows binaries at least... suppose, first people to try and use it are Windows users. So, same problem here - it's much more pain not to distribute MinGW's GCC dll's along with executable for Windows users.

Comment: I can't tell about Windows, not knowing it (except for the *DLL hell* phrase applied to it). But **distributing `libc.so.6` or `libstdc++.so.6` with your software is a huge mistake** on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You should not redistribute those 5 libraries as most modern Linux systems will already have them available. Should you decide to redistribute them regardless, you would also be required to make their source available; read the LGPL (or a summary) for details.

Comment: But making source available could be done by linking to GNU site or directly to source rpms of glibc, glibc-devel and libstdc++...

Comment: *You* must make them available.

Comment: Pity... OMG, bigger problem in Windows - I'll use MinGW compiler and can't expect `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and `libstdc++6.dll` being available on user's machine. 

BTW, some windows binaries compiled under cygwin do include cygwin1.dll and stuff...